# Enable Google IAM API Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

is there anyway to enable IAM API through python. However, I dont see any methods mentioned in Google documentaion. I have gone through this link https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#gcloud but it only describes enabling service API via, gcloud or curl.

Is there anyway I can enable it via Python?

Answer (score 2):

The API you want to use is Service Usage

Link to the REST API:

[Service Usage API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest)

Link to the Python API:

[Python API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/serviceusage_v1beta1.html)

Example code that I wrote to use the Python API to list services:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services
# https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

project = 'projects/development-xxxxxx'

service = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

next = None

totalCount = 0

while 1:
    request = service.services().list(parent=project, pageToken=next)

    response = ''

    try:
        response = request.execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

    services = response.get('services')

    for index in range(len(services)):
        totalCount += 1

        item = services[index]

        name = item['config']['name']
        state = item['state']

        print("%-50s %s" % (name, state))

    next = response.get('nextPageToken')

    # print('NEXT:', next)

    if next == None:
        break;

print('')
print('Total number of services:', totalCount)
```

To enable a service call the enable method:

[API to enable a service](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/serviceusage_v1beta1.services.html#enable)